# c# how to update a field in a dataTable

Tags: c#, .net, datatable

I have a .net/ c# console app with a `DataTable` that I populated from a Database.

I want to run an update on a field in the `DataTable` to strip the HTML. the function i have in the console app to do this is called: `StripTagsCharArray`

its defined as:

```
static private string StripTagsCharArray(string source)
```

how can i invoke this to update the Description field in my `DataTable`?

i want to see if this will improve performance of my application as now i have a SQL UDF doing the HTML stripping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in case some one needs this:

```
foreach (DataRow row in tmp.Rows)
            {
                row["Description"] = StripTagsCharArray(row["Description"].ToString());
            }
```